# Batch file gets number of bytes returned from a web request and use in a conditional statement

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement

I am making a curl POST request to get data from an API and then **based on the number of bytes returned I need to decide whether or not to save the data to the file**.  I'm doing this because I don't want to overwrite the current data file if the response returns an empty data set.  I figured the best way to check for this would be to make sure the response was at least a certain number of bytes.

Here I am making a POST request and saving the response data to the file data.json.

```
:: if response_bytes > 1000 then do the command below
    @echo off
    (
        curl --insecure -X POST "https://nimbus.redborder.net/api/data?auth_token=12345" -H  "content-type: application/json" -d @query.body
    ) > data.json
```

**Solution**

```
curl --insecure -X POST "https://nimbus.redborder.net/api/data?auth_token=12345" -H  "content-type: application/json" -d @query.body > data.json

for %%a in ("data.json") do set "$Bytes=%%~za"

if defined $Bytes if %$Bytes% geq 1000 (type data.json >> new_data.json) else (echo Less than 1000 bytes)
```

Comment: Why the downvote?  If there is a better way to do it, I would love a suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `delimiter` `%~z` ==> (`For /?`), you can get the number of bytes of your `data.json` file and then just making an `if` test against the received value in `%$Bytes%` :

**EDIT :**

```
@echo off
set /a $Bytes=0

if exist "data.json" (
  for %%a in ("data.json") do set "$Bytes=%%~za"
  if %$Bytes% GEQ 1000 (type data.json >> new_data.json) else (echo Less than 1000 bytes)
  exit/b
)

echo Error.. File not found [data.json]
```

Comment: My code already captures the output of the curl request.  What I need to know is how to get the number of bytes from the request and then use it in an if-statement. ex. if ( res_bytes > 1000) ...

Comment: See my solution I used from your answer, does it look right?

Comment: Effectively i made a mistake ! Check my EDIT ! Now it's OK